# DIY door frame pull-up bar

Tags: doors, frame

I came to posses an amazing, strong metal alloy bar that would fit my door frame perfectly! I'd like to turn this into a pull-up bar and hang it onto the frame.

- What is the name of the things that I can screw into the frame on which the straight bar can rest?

Comment: Brackets of some sort. Could be as simple as wood blocks with a hole drilled or cut into them...

Comment: hey @keshlam thanks! would you like to post this as an answer for me to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are closet rod hangers like these: [image: Rod hanger]

but I wouldn't really recommend any kind of free standing hardware. The problem is, no matter how you secure them, there will be a pretty significant amount of shear force on your jamb material. Most jambs are made out of inferior stock and will probably crack if you subject them to that kind of strain. The safest bet is to attach a full length support to either side like so:[image]

This way the load is transferred down into the floor. In this example you have to remove the existing door stop and apply the support in the same position so that it acts as your stop. Run your screws into the space where the stop was, that way you if you should decide to remove your supports later on you can return your door to its original state with out having to fill a bunch of holes.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I hope you didn't go through the trouble of designing that 3D stuff just for me =)) Many thanks!

Comment: Nah, Google Sketchup makes it pretty quick and easy, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the rod, you might be able to use Closet Bar Brackets.  You can typically find these in wood but sometimes you can find them in metal.  And if that doesn't work, try some Pipe Flanges.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to mount these to the door frame where the door will still be able to close?

Comment: Closet bar brackets are small enough to fit in the door jam.  Just use 2+ inch long screws to mount so you go through the door jam and into the wood frame.  A hardware store will have the closet bar brackets and then buy a small box of screws there as well.